# What does "seize from" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> They left the hall quickly, wanting to unwrap the broomstick in
>   private before their first class, but halfway across the entrance hall
>   they found the way upstairs barred by Crabbe and Goyle. Malfoy
>   **seized** the package **from** Harry and felt it. 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

When the verb *seize* is combined with *from*, does it mean the broomstick left Harry’s hand or do both the boys hold it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - *seized* here means *took [violently, by force]*. And *from* can be read as ***away*** from, which implies Harry no longer had "possession" (he wasn't still holding it, since it was *taken away*).

Answer (score 3):

To *seize* means to *take*. To *take something from someone* is to remove it from their possession and place it into yours; to *take it* ***away*** *from them*. So yes, Malfoy took the broom away from Harry, and now Malfoy is holding it and Harry is not.